# Dao and JpaRepositories throwing NullPointerException when @Autowiring

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

**Problem:** 
 Autowiring SingerDaoImpl and JpaRepositoryImpl Bean results in a null result. No Exception is throw, but no Data is returned. Using Thymeleaf view to display data

**Technologies Used:** 
 Spring, JpaRepository, Hibernate, Thymeleaf, H2 Embedded DB (Script located in resources/SQL folder), Spring MVC, javax.validation.

I use localhost:8080/singers to list the singers through thymeleaf located in resources/templates/listSingers.html. Upon calling the /singers controller the number of singers retrieved is logged to the console through logger

**Things I crossed out:**

- No @Component(or its specializations) Class is declared with the new operator

- All beans that are @Autowired are Annotated with @Component, @Repository, or @Service

- Setters are already setup, 

- @Qualifier is already pointing to the correct bean

- The Embedded Database IS populated with data as located in resources/SQL/test.sql and added through DBConfig.java class with the EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.addScript("SQL/test.sql") method

- All dependencies in gradle.build file version is managed by gradle to be the latest version

**Link to github page:**

 https://github.com/NikitaDyagilev/LearningSprinbMVC

note: I'm using Amazon Corretto Java 11

**DBConfig.java**

```
package com.example.demo.Config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.JpaRepo"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DBconfig {

     @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
     private String driverClassName;
     @Value("${jdbc.username}")
     private String username;
     @Value("${jdbc.password}")
     private String password;
     @Value("${jdbc.url}")
     private String url;

     private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBconfig.class);

//   MySQL DataSource Connection
     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSourceR(){
          try{
               SimpleDriverDataSource db =
                       new SimpleDriverDataSource();
               Class<? extends Driver> driver =
                       (Class<? extends Driver>) Class.forName(driverClassName);
               db.setDriverClass(driver);
               db.setUsername(username);
               db.setPassword(password);
               db.setUrl(url);
               return db;
          } catch (Exception e){
               logger.error("Something Went wrong when trying to Create the MySQL DataSource bean");
               return null;
          }
     }

//   Embedded DataSource Connection
     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSourceE(){
          try{
               EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder db =
                       new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
               db.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
               db.addScript("SQL/table.sql");
               db.addScript("SQL/test.sql");
               return db.build();
          } catch (Exception e ){
               logger.error("There was an error when trying to create Embeded DataSource: ", e);
               return null;
          }
     }

     @Bean
     public Properties hibernaProperties(){
          Properties prop = new Properties();
          prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
//          prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
          prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
          prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
          prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
          prop.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
          prop.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
          prop.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
          return prop;
     }

     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
          return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
     }

     @Bean
     public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
          return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
     }

     @Bean(name ="entityManagerFactory")
     public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb =
                  new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          emfb.setDataSource(dataSourceE());
          emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demo.Model");
          emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
          emfb.setJpaProperties(hibernaProperties());
          emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
          emfb.afterPropertiesSet();
          return emfb.getObject();
     }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```java
package com.example.demo.Controllers;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);


    private SingerDao dao;

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello There";
    }

    @GetMapping(value ="/homepage")
    public String homepageListing(){
        return "homepage";
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/singers")
    public String listSingers(Model model){
        logger.info("Listing Singers:");
        List<Singer> singers = dao.findAll();
        String[] names = new String[singers.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            names[i] = singers.get(i).getFirstName();
        }
        model.addAttribute("singersNames", names);
        return "ListSingers";
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/getSinger{id}")
    public String getSingerById(Model model,@PathVariable Long id){
        model.addAttribute("singer", dao.findById(id).getFirstName());
        return "getSinger";
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(SingerDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

**JpaRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.JpaRepo;


@Repository("jpaRepositoryImpl")
public class JpaRepositoryImpl implements JpaRepository {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public List<Singer> findAll() {
        return emf.createEntityManager()
                .createQuery("select s from singer s")
                .getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Singer> findById(Long aLong) {
        return (Optional<Singer>) emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("select s from singer s where s.id = ?id").
                setParameter("id",aLong).getSingleResult();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "entityManagerFactory")
    public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
}
```

**DAO service**

```
package com.example.demo.DAO;


@Service("singerDaoImpl")
public class SingerDaoImpl implements SingerDao {

    private JpaRepository jpaRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Singer> findAll() {
        List<Singer> singers = new ArrayList<>();
        jpaRepo.findAll().forEach(item -> singers.add(item));
        System.out.println("# Of Singers: "+singers.size());
        return singers;
    }

    @Override
    public Singer findById(Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="jpaRepositoryImpl")
    public void setJpaRepo(JpaRepository jpaRepo) {
        this.jpaRepo = jpaRepo;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
package com.example.demo.Model;

@Table(name="singer")
@Entity(name="singer")
public class Singer implements Serializable{

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="id")
     private Long id;

     @NotEmpty(message = "{validation.firstname.NotEmpty.message}")
     @Size(min=3,max=60,message="{validation.firstname.Size.message}")
     @Column(name="first_name")
     private String firstName;

     @NotEmpty(message = "{validation.lastname.NotEmpty.message}")
     @Size(min=3,max=60,message ="{validation.lastname.Size.message")
     @Column(name="last_name")
     private String lastName;

     @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
     @Column(name="birth_date")
     private Date birthDate;

     @Column(name="description")
     private String description;

     @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @Lob
     @Column(name="photo")
     private byte photo;

     public Long getId() {
          return id;
     }

     public void setId(Long id) {
          this.id = id;
     }

     public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
          this.firstName = firstName;
     }

     public String getLastName() {
          return lastName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String lastName) {
          this.lastName = lastName;
     }

     public Date getDate() {
          return birthDate;
     }

     public void setDate(Date date) {
          this.birthDate = date;
     }

     public String getDescription() {
          return description;
     }

     public void setDescription(String description) {
          this.description = description;
     }

     public byte getPhoto() {
          return photo;
     }

     public void setPhoto(byte photo) {
          this.photo = photo;
     }

     @Transient
     public String getBirthDateString(){
          String birthDateString = "";
          if(birthDate != null){
               SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
                    birthDateString = sdf.format(birthDate);
          }
          return birthDateString;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
          return "Singer{" +
                  "id=" + id +
                  ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                  ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                  ", birthDate=" + birthDate +
                  ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                  ", photo=" + photo +
                  '}';
     }
}
```

*Edit:*
I added logging.level.org.springframework = debug

Here is the relevant portion of the console

```
2020-05-26 11:26:13.500  INFO 14664 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2935 ms
2020-05-26 11:26:13.508 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'requestContextFilter'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.513 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'formContentFilter'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.513 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.519 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'characterEncodingFilter'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.531 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
2020-05-26 11:26:13.532 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2020-05-26 11:26:13.565 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2020-05-26 11:26:13.565 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2020-05-26 11:26:13.566 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
2020-05-26 11:26:13.585 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'demoApplication'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.586 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'DBconfig'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.591 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.driverClassName' in PropertySource 'applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.591 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.driverClassName' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.593 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.username' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.593 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.username' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.595 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.password' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.595 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.password' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.595 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.url' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.595 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'jdbc.url' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
2020-05-26 11:26:13.599 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'testController'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.607 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'singerDaoImpl'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.614 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaRepositoryImpl'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.621 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.673 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSourceE'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.702  INFO 14664 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2020-05-26 11:26:13.712 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2020-05-26 11:26:13.713 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]
2020-05-26 11:26:13.971 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [SQL/table.sql]
2020-05-26 11:26:14.002 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE SINGER ( ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(60), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(40), BIRTH_DATE DATE, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000) NULL, PHOTO BLOB NULL, VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, UNIQUE UQ_SINGER_1 (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME), PRIMARY KEY (ID) )
2020-05-26 11:26:14.002 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [SQL/table.sql] in 30 ms.
2020-05-26 11:26:14.002 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [SQL/test.sql]
2020-05-26 11:26:14.014 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('John', 'Mayer', '1977-10-16')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.014 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Eric', 'Clampton', '1954-03-20')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.017 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('John', 'Butler', '1975-04-01')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.017 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('B.B' , 'King', '1925-09-16')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.019 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Jimi', 'Hendrix', '1942-11-27')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.021 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Eddie', 'Van Halen','1955-01-26')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.022 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Saul Slash', 'Hudson', '1965-07-23')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.023 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Stevie', 'Ray Vaughan','1954-10-03')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.023 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('David', 'Gilmour','1946-03-06')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.026 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Kirk','Hammett','1992-11-18')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.027 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Angus','Young','1955-03-31')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.028 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Dimebad','Darrell','1966-08-20')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.029 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Carlos','Santana','1947-07-20')
2020-05-26 11:26:14.030 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [SQL/test.sql] in 28 ms.
2020-05-26 11:26:14.039 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.043 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.064 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker' via constructor to bean named 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.065 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker' via constructor to bean named 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@456d6c1e'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.227 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'hibernaProperties'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.230 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jpaVendorAdapter'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.245 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-26 11:26:14.294  INFO 14664 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-26 11:26:14.412  INFO 14664 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-26 11:26:14.685  INFO 14664 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-26 11:26:14.906 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]
2020-05-26 11:26:14.940  INFO 14664 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate:
```

**SQL Query***

```
drop table if exists singer CASCADE 
2020-05-26 11:26:16.139 DEBUG 14664 --- [           main] o.s.j.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource  : Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]
Hibernate: 

    create table singer (
       id bigint generated by default as identity,
        birth_date date,
        description varchar(255),
        first_name varchar(255),
        last_name varchar(255),
        photo blob,
        primary key (id)
    )
```

***I found an expression***

```
javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291) ~[validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:257) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(ValidatorAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, don't let people browse your full repo to find the offending classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum got it sorry about that

Comment: Can you please add "logging.level.org.springframework = debug" to your application.properties and share whats logging for SingerDaoImpl and JpaRepositoryImpl

Comment: @AliD.A. sure, I tried to pick the most relevant part

Comment: Is there any log for your select query or your SingerDaoImpl bean auto wiring with dao class variable ?

Comment: yes, I will post it on here

Comment: The exception is irrelevant. Post the nullpointerexception you get.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't get it, but when I tried to Autowire the SingerDaoImpl class in a seperate file it would throw me the null pointer exception. But the SpringBoot server runs it just does not return the data from the embedded DB I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. In fact, your database *was* empty. Why? Because of this line in your DBConfig class.
`prop.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");` ([link to the documentation for this property](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)). You can safely delete it or set the property to a value that makes sense for you.

You will also need to set the photo attribute (and the getters&setters for it) in your Singer class to `Byte` (This kind of type is also called a [Wrapper Class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wrapper-classes-java/)) instead of `byte` since byte is a primitive value that cannot be set to null. In your DB script however, you allow photo to be null so, if you dont change this code, it will cause an exception when trying to map the DB columns into Java objects.Once youve down these two things, the list of singers will be shown in the browser.

Now, some final tips since you are somewhat new to programming:

I've checked out your repo and you're doing a lot of work and configuration that you do not have to do since you are using Spring Boot and Spring Boot Data Jpa and not simply Spring. I would encourage you to start using Spring Boot to its full extent first and then learn Spring and how to customize it to your needs, if you ever need solely Spring at all for your needs.[Use this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot) as a gateway to learn more about Spring Boot and Spring Boot Data Jpa.